# Muons that decay in plastic scintillator

Tags: energy, particle-physics

I have a question on the energy of the muons that decay in a plastic scintillator.

In [these notes](https://www.physlab.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Muon_cali.pdf), at page 4, fourth line from the end, it is mentioned that

> muons with less than about 50 MeV will stop in the scintillator (about 0.3%.)

It seems that the  0.3% mention is taken  from the Bruno Rossi book, *High Energy Particles* (Prentice Hall, 1952). Unfortunately my local library can't provide me the book.

I would be very grateful = if someone who owns the book could check up if the 0.3 % mention is explained somewhere and share the information with me.

Comment: I conjecture that it means that 0.3% of the cosmic muons will be below 50 MeV and be caught in the scintilator. see figure 30.5 here http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2017-rev-cosmic-rays.pdf.  Is there no library in your university?

Comment: I agree with @anna's understanding of the meaning of the figure but would mention that the exact value could fairly easily vary by a factor of two in either direction depending on local latitude and elevation (it depends a lot on the local height an density of the atmosphere).